# How can I upload the code as described in the platform? (E-commerce details page)

Tags: html, css

```css
.mk_01{
    
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.mk_02{
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;   
}
.mk_banner1{
    width: 1800px;
    height: 443px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>M7</title>
<link href="css/geshi.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="mk_01"><strong>PRÉSENTATION PRODUIT</strong></div>
<div class="mk_02">Dido Enceinte bluetooth, Haut-Parleur Portable Sans Fil Résistant à l'eau avec 12 Heures de Travail, Bluetooth 5.0 stéréo Subwoofer</div>
<section>
    <div class="mk_banner1">
      <div class="mk_banner01"><img src="tupian/banner1.png" width="1100" height="443" alt=""/>
      </div>
        <div class="mk_yinzhi">SON ET SOPHISTICATION SUPERIEURS</div>
      <div class="mk_yinzhi_1">Enceinte intelligente multifonction au son immersif</div>
</div></section>
<section><body>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

E-commerce product detail codes, but the platform has many restrictions. For example, the upload code format cannot contain styles such as . It cannot exceed 5000 characters. How can I upload the code according to the description of the platform?

Comment: Rules of the platform:1、HTML forbidden: <href> <font> <table> <tr> <td> <th> <h1> <h2> <h3> <h4> <h5> <h6 > <body>

Comment: HTML forbidden: 2、On the marketing description only: add HTML code for a quality description (URL links must be in https: //)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, such sites have a lots of restriction. What you can try is using the following sites to compress your css and html code. It will make it's readability almost 0 but should allow you to fit lots of characters.
For css https://csscompressor.com/ for html  https://htmlcompressor.com/
If this doesn't work as well, you may have to delete some parts of your code to make it fit into their criteria. But give those sites a go, just copy and paste your codes, it will provide the compressed version, copy paste that into that e commerce site. If asked, select 'most compresssed/ 0 readability' to compress it to max.

EDIT : After seeing your comments, it feels like using body is not allowed as well, which  you have used. Could you provide the actual rules of the site?

EDIT 2: No where have they mentioned that they want a css code. They only want a good structured html code for the product description and marketing description. You need to have only 420 characters in the product description, only text. As for marketing description you can include images as well and limit it upto 5000 characters. They don't require a css code and hence you are not able to submit.

Comment: The " Product Description " (short) is limited to 420 characters and appears on the site next to the image. It is used to give essential information to the customer and is therefore mandatory. It does not allow the addition of HTML code.  
The "  Marketing Description  " (long) is limited to 5000 characters and allows you to give more information about the product as well as add images, videos and HTML code . It appears on the site when you click on the link "See product presentation". It is optional but strongly recommended to increase your visibility.

Comment: Good practices :
Provide your information in a clear and structured way
Text in French
Construct sentences with subjects, verbs, complements, avoid telegraphic style so that the consumer is properly informed about the product
Quality spelling
On the marketing description only: add HTML code for a quality description (URL links must be in https: //). For more information on this subject, please contact the Product Integration department via the "Help" section.

Comment: Be careful with the tags used for the HTML code: 
HTML allowed: <bold> <strong> <br>
HTML forbidden: <href> <font> <table> <tr> <td> <th> <h1> <h2> <h3> <h4> <h5> <h6 > <body>

Comment: The main ones are almost these

Comment: My css file does not know how to call it before it will be recognized by the platform

Comment: No one is it written that you need to provide a css file as well. That is why it is not getting accepted. Please check my answer for a much better explanation

Comment: https://www.cdiscount.com/high-tech/enceintes-sans-fil-bluetooth/jbl-charge-4-enceintes-bluetooth-portable-20-heu/f-10684-jbl6925281939990.html#mpos=0|cd                                         But other sellers on the platform can show this effect. How do you think his code was written? thank you very much

Comment: Are you trying to sell on the linked website? Usually such kinds of site have sort of template design for all the other effects you see. In a simpler sense, they are already there. What this website wants from you is the descriptions. And you may have seen product description contains images, and all that. This explains why they don't want you to have headings(h1) or table since descriptions dont have all that. As for the icons, you can easily use ```< i class = "your icon name"> </i> ``` replace the name with whatever icon image you want, you can get them from here https://ionicons.com/v2/

Comment: Yes, I want to sell on this platform. This platform does not have relevant templates and can only be written in code. What if the css file is introduced into the body and recognized by the platform?

Comment: Well, as far as I know, if the website itself doesn't support css styling and also mentions what not to have in your html code, the only option is to have the standard html code as specified. Have you actually tried uploading a plain html first? Maybe they may give more options after that. Also it's quite rare for a sales website to ask users to provide a html file for their product. Not gonna lie, sounds fishy to me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience, I will try to upload pure html files